# Pass env file to detox

Tags: react-native, detox, react-native-config

I would like to pass environment variable when I run detox tests in my react-native app:

```
 "ios.sim.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app",
    "build": "export IS_DETOX=true && xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -scheme my app -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "device": {
      "type": "iPhone 11 Pro"
    }
  }
```

I've installed [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config). But the variable IS_DETOX is undefined in JS when I run detox tests.

Thanks

Comment: Your `IS_DETOX` variable is defined in the build step. Why would you expect it to be there in runtime?

Comment: do you know how can I made this variable accessible in runtime then? I want for instance to disable animations and toast/alert messages in the detox build thanks to an env var like IS_DETOX

Comment: You can use launch arguments, environment variables for the process or mock your stuff. Read the Detox docs.

Comment: @GChevass Have you figured out how to do it? Could you please post an answer if you did so?

Comment: I was able to make it running with `.env` in root folder. It got pick automatically by Detox

Comment: @Black and what if I don't want to use default .env file but something like .env.test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am setting environmental variable without `export`.

All my .env variables are stored in config folder and I am able to load different environmental file for different configurations.

**iOS**

```js
"ios.sim.release": {
  "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Clim8Invest.app",
  "build": "ENVFILE=config/.env.acceptance xcodebuild -workspace ios/Clim8Invest.xcworkspace -scheme Clim8Invest -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
  "type": "ios.simulator",
  "device": {
    "type": "iPhone 11"
  }
},
```

**Android**

```js
"android.emu.debug.e2e": {
  "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
  "build": "cd android && ENVFILE=../config/.env.e2e ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
  "type": "android.emulator",
  "device": {
    "avdName": "Nexus_5X_A"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Black !

On my side I ended up using another solution with `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js` from [Detox Mocking Guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md) so that the detox build is using params from `MyConfig.e2e.js` file instead of `MyConfig.js` file